# How to write filter regex snap sparql in java code using owl api

Tags: java, filter, sparql, owl, protege

oke, i have this snap sparql code

```
    SELECT ?resep_makanan
WHERE {
    ?resep_makanan rdf:type :resep_makanan.
    ?resep_makanan :resep_untuk :6-7_bulan.
    ?malnutrisi rdf:type :malnutrisi.
    ?malnutrisi :memiliki_penawar ?resep_makanan.
    FILTER regex(str(?malnutrisi),"beriberi")
}
ORDER BY ?resep_makanan
```

it works just fine in protege 5.5.0
how should i write it in java code?
FYI : im using owl api

Comment: given that you didn't show what you did in your previous question, I'll keep it short at let you do it alone: https://github.com/owlcs/ont-api

Comment: sorry, but i mean this a different kind of question. because its contain filter regex @UninformedUser

Comment: OWL API doesn't support SPARQL. Do you mean a different API?

Comment: @Ignazio I'm sure she means OWL API but is always forgetting to say that she tried with SPARQL-DL API already - she never told me the details, so I couldn't help further ... but I guess, SPARQL-DL doesn't support filter expressions at all. Regarding OWL API and SPARQL, I'm sure you're also aware of the [Ont API](https://github.com/owlcs/ont-api), which is basically a bridge between OWL API and Jena, thus, you can use SPARQL in OWL API and some OWL API stuff like OWL 2 axioms in Jena.

Comment: @AstridNovianaParadhita use Ont API as I referred to in my comment. Wiki and examples are online

Comment: I am aware, hence the request for clarification. The question as it stands is at least incomplete and cannot be answered.

Comment: oh yeah, maybe its because there are many things i didnt understand yet. So, im really sorry guys, i will do a little study again about owl api, jena and ont api. Thanks before @UninformedUser